# Looping an array and making it empty. Why it behaves wierd?

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm

Why the loop is still getting executed 3 times after making the array empty

Below is a code snippet from my playground.

```
var arr = [12, 34, 45]
for _ in arr {
    arr = []
    print("A")
}
```

Result:

```
A
A
A
```

Comment: In this kind of `for` loop, an iterator is created over the values of the array before entering the loop and waiting for its `next()` to be `nil`. You can check it with this code `for x in arr {arr = []; print(x)}`

Comment: You aren't making the array empty; you are creating a new empty array and assigning a reference to it to the variable `arr`. The iterator that you're using in the loop still holds a reference to the original array.

Comment: Int and Array are value types, so they are always passed(copy) by value.

Comment: Arrays are value types in Swift https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10

Comment: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/8551

Comment: When you say `var arr = [12, 34, 45]; for _ in arr {` that is the same as saying `var arr = [12, 34, 45];
for _ in [12, 34, 45] {`. What you do to `arr` now does not affect the integrity of the loop.

Answer (score 7):

**TL;DR**

A copy of the array is created by the for-in loop (behind the scenes, for-in loop are using iterators).

---

When using a for loop, Swift is creating an iterator to loop over all the elements

```swift
let animals = ["Antelope", "Butterfly", "Camel", "Dolphin"]
for animal in animals {
    print(animal)
}
```

is the same as

```swift
var animalIterator = animals.makeIterator()
while let animal = animalIterator.next() {
    print(animal)
}
```

(See [IteratorProtocol documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/iteratorprotocol))

So the behavior depends on how the Array iterator work. If we take a look at the `makeIterator()` methods on `Array`, it returns an `IndexingIterator<Array<Element>>`.

This `IndexingIterator` is a `struct` (value type), which is initialized using the array itself (which is also value type). A copy of the array is created and iterated over when the iterator is created (`makeIterator()` call).

```swift
public struct IndexingIterator<Elements: Collection> {
  // [...]

  init(_elements: Elements) {
    self._elements = _elements
    self._position = _elements.startIndex
  }

  public mutating func next() -> Elements.Element? {
    if _position == _elements.endIndex { return nil }
    let element = _elements[_position]
    _elements.formIndex(after: &_position)
    return element
  }

  // [...]
}
```

In the `next()` method, `IndexingIterator` is using the copied array (`_elements`) to provide the next value.
(See [Collection.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/da61cc8cdf7aa2bfb3ab03200c52c4d371dc6751/stdlib/public/core/Collection.swift))

Answer (score 1):

for-in loop to iterate over a sequence, such as items in an array, ranges of numbers, or characters in a string. Once you give a range to loop it will repeat code with a for loop and make your code more expressive and elegant.

In your case, you said that for loop has to repeat code as per array item. For loop will repeat code 3 times.

For more details, You can refer to these links.

1. [Swift Docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html)
2. [For Loops In Swift](https://learnappmaking.com/loops-swift-how-to/)

I hope this will be helpful to you. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You iterating a copy here. The `for in` loop is designed to give you copies of value types.